# How to make a button in C# Make a text file and add the result of a textbox to it and then show it in the program?

Tags: c#

I have a button (let's call it button1), a textbox (let's call it textbox1) and another textbox (let's call it textbox2). - Windows Form Application in C#
So i've made it that you need to write how long you want the characters to be in textbox2 (e.x 9) when button1 is clicked to generate random 9 characters (like D0yZk@!eA - depending how many characters you've set it to in textbox2) to textbox1. It can generate from 1 to 99 characters, that's just an example.

So my question is how to make in C# when button1 is clicked, the result from textbox1 to go to a text file in a new line which to be included in the program in which i can scroll in to see what i have generated? Like a textbox (but that textbox's content to be a textfile that all generated things will be in a new line) that show's all or the latest generated things in a new line each that is only readable.

Comment: Did you try to read a tutorial or book? Post your best try and your specific problem.

Comment: I woudn't be asking for help if i didn't see a tutorial, also i'm new with C#.

Comment: You mentioned 'text file' only in question header

Comment: Just did it myself. Added this ( http://pastebin.com/a8aBWHtf ) to button2 code (the button that generates the characters and sends them to textBox2 - the generated characters are sent to textBox2 and now listBox1 takes it's content from textBox2.) Thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a ListBox to your form and call it `listBox1`. Then add a click event to `button1`, and do something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int length;

    // We use TryParse to make sure it is a number, otherwise
    // we tell the user and return;.
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out length)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Not a number!");
        return;
    }

    // Make a random string
    string myString = RandomString(length);

    // Show it in the text box
    textBox1.Text = myString;

    // ... and in the listbox
    listBox1.Items.Add(myString);
}
```

The function for a random string could look like this:

```
string RandomString(int length) {
    string options = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!#%&/()=?";

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(length);
    Random random = new Random();

    // Add the characters one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Get a random index in our character options string.
        int randomIndex = random.Next(options.Length);

        // Add the random character
        str.Append(options[randomIndex]);
    }

    // Make a string of the StringBuilder and return it.
    return str.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for but thanks. At least you tried unlike some people that came to only downvote this instead of helping.